# HTML 5 usage in Desktop Browser and Mobile Browser

Tags: html, web

Can same HTML 5 markup be used in both the desktop browser and Mobile browsers ???Would i have to create a different markup for Mobile browsers(Iphone ,Android etc) and that will be uniform accross different mobile platforms ??

Answer (score 1):

No, in general you do not need to create different markup for desktop and mobile devices. You can specify differences via [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) in css.

Answer (score 1):

In theory yes.. But the browsers implementation can in fact be different.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @madhead & @Burrhus;

It is your choice but the difference come from the width and height difference between mobile and PC browsers.

In my opinion, the thing which you have to think is about usage of application and the application's size.